# How to improve Jquerymobile scrolling performance in large lists

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

When scrolling lists built with JQueryMobile list widget, it looks choppy. A big contrast to what the phone is capable of ...

How to improve this?

Can use iScroll4, supposed to have better performance, but its heavy when compared to jquery.mobile.listview.js

Also I like the filtering capability in the JQuery list widget.

All suggestions welcome!

Thank you,

M

Answer (score 0):

Have you looks at the jQM Experiments?

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview

Also List performance:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/lists-performance.html